# Search header and return all values below from corresponding column

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Trying to wrap an `INDEX`/`MATCH` function in `ARRAYFORMULA` without success.

Here is what I have so far:

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN(", ",TRANSPOSE(INDEX(data!$B$2:$E$4,,ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B),MATCH(B2:B,data!$B$1:$E$1,0),)),))))
```

My objective is to search the column headings of a sheet and when a match is found, display a CSV array of all of the values below the matching header.  My formula does that much, but what I really need to do at this point is somehow convert it to a single formula rather than drag/copy it down the column.

[my sample worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ej0aiu5thFeOQMa-jIYwSHzwfr7sGLtDAVPbJKcJfS4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, TRANSPOSE({data!B1:E1; 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(IF(data!B2:E<>"", data!B2:E&",", )
 ,,999^99)), ",$", )}), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]